# Handling infinities in Dygraph

Tags: dygraphs

Here is a nice dygraph

```js
var data = [1,2,3,3,2].map((d,i) => [i, d]);

new Dygraph(document.getElementById("demodiv"), data, {labels: ["Date", "series1"]});
```

```html
<script src="http://dygraphs.com/dygraph-combined.js"></script>

<div id="demodiv"></div>
```

But here is what if one of the samples is Infinity like 4/0

```js
var infty = 4/0
var data = [1,2,infty,3,2].map((d,i) => [i, d]);

new Dygraph(document.getElementById("demodiv"), data, {labels: ["Date", "series1"]});
```

```html
<script src="http://dygraphs.com/dygraph-combined.js"></script>

<div id="demodiv"></div>
```

All the graph disappears somewhere. What is the supposed solution?

Answer (score 0):

I have solved the problem to some extent, by precomputing the max value

```js
var data = [1,2,4/0,3,10,2,1,0/0,2,1]
var filtered = data.filter(a => !(a == Infinity || isNaN(a)))
var r = ['min', 'max'].map(name => Math[name]).map(f => f(...filtered))
new Dygraph(document.getElementById("demodiv"), data.map((d,i) => [i, d])
 , {labels: ["Date", "series1"], valueRange:r});
```

```html
<script src="http://dygraphs.com/dygraph-combined.js"></script>

<div id="demodiv"></div>
```

As you see, the infinity that we have at x=2 is simply ignored. I wish however, that the graph displays it going vertically up beyond the "roof" to visualize the infinity. I had to do it manually

```js
var data = [1,2,4/0,3,10,2,1,0/0,2,1]
var filtered = data.filter(a => !(a == Infinity || isNaN(a)))
var r = ['min', 'max'].map(name => Math[name]).map(f => f(...filtered))

// map infinities to large numbers. These nums are too large for the displayed range and did not participate in visible range definition
//var m = new Map(); m.set(Infinity, Number.MAX_VALUE); m.set(-Infinity, Number.MIN_VALUE) // min/max are too large for the Dygraph
var m = new Map(); m.set(Infinity, 1e7); m.set(-Infinity, -1e7)
data = data.map(a => m.get(a) || a) 

new Dygraph(document.getElementById("demodiv"), data.map((d,i) => [i, d])
 , {labels: ["Date", "series1"], valueRange:r});
```

```html
<script src="http://dygraphs.com/dygraph-combined.js"></script>

<div id="demodiv"></div>
```

This however makes another problem: the value labels are also converted from `Infinity` to `1e7`. When you hover a mouse over the graph, you see that the value is `1e7` rather than Infinity.